# Replacing Null Values Using Derived Column in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a data flow task which picks up data from a non-unicode flat file to a SQL Server table destination.

I'm using a `Derived Column` task to replace `NULL` values in a date column with the string "1900-01-01". The destination table column is a `varchar` data type.

I'm using this SSIS Expression `(DT_STR,10,1252)REPLACENULL(dateColumn,"1900-01-01")` and the task executes successfully but I still see `NULLs` instead of the "1900-01-01" string at the destination.

Why is this? I've tried replacing the column, adding a new column but whatever I do I still see `NULLs` and not the replacement string. I can see my new derived column in the `Advanced Editor` so can see no reason why this isn't working. Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: Do you have better luck using a inline if expression? `ISNULL(dateColumn) == True ? (DT_STR,10,1252) "1900-01-01" : dateColumn`

Comment: what is datatype of destination column  ?

Comment: @BHouse he says it in his question: The destination table column is a varchar data type.

Answer (score 0):

If your your source is non-unicode, why are you using DT_STR? varchar is a already a non-unicode data-type. You should just be able to do it with

`REPLACENULL(dateColumn,"1900-01-01")`

Also, did you put in a lookup transformation to update the column? Have you made sure the right keys are being looked up and updated?